# Best way to mask textbox control to allow string value in a pair of 3 character using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to mask a textbox control to allow string value in a pair of 3 character using java script.

Eg:- I have a Text box control zip code in which when a user gives input then it should automatically pair them in a pair of 3 character (ABC#123), and total length of input is 6 Max.

Is it possible then how??

Comment: do you mean if user enters abc123 then it should be changed to abc#123?

Comment: when user input ABC123 then it should display ABC(SPACE)123

Answer (score 0):

```
  var text="ABC123";

    //you can add any validation if you require like to check the length of string
   //if(text.length<=6)

var output=text.substring(0,3)+" "+text.substring(3);
```

[check this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ucv4T/5/)